# ipython do not add a new line

Tags: python, ipython

Consider the ipython repl:

```py
$ ipython
Python 3.6.8 (default, Aug  7 2019, 17:28:10)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.16.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

[ins] In [1]: x = 2

[ins] In [2]: y = 2

[ins] In [3]:
```

In contrast, consider the normal python repl:

```py
$ python
Python 3.6.8 (default, Aug  7 2019, 17:28:10)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = 2
>>> y = 2
>>>
```

As you can see, ipython repl adds a lot of unnecessary (my opinion) new line statements, while the python repl is a lot more concise.

Is there a way in which I can disable those new lines? (Note that I am aware of this: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/details.html where one can change what gets displayed on prompt. However, I can't find an option to disable the new lines in between prompts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start `ipython` with the `--nosep` option.

```
$ ipython --nosep
Python 3.8.3 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jun  1 2020, 17:43:00) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.16.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
In [1]: x = 1                                                                                                                                                                   
In [2]: y = 2                                                                                                                                                                   
In [3]: print(x, y)                                                                                                                                                             
1 2
In [4]:
```

From `ipython --help`:

```
--nosep
    Eliminate all spacing between prompts.
```

One can also achieve this behavior by setting this configuration option:

```
c.InteractiveShell.separate_in = ''
```

Comment: Ah, that's embarrassing.

Would you mind editing your answer to also include:
One can change this in the configuration file via `c.InteractiveShell.separate_in = ''`?